# How to check if android device is having a internet connection from server?

Tags: android

I am making an android application where I need to check whether an android device is having an active internet connection or not. I can do that from an application but how do I check it from the server without touching an android device?

Option 1:  Make a service that will send the request to a server every 5 mins. Is it alright or is there any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
try{
    URL myUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    connection.connect();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle your exceptions
    return false;
}
}
```